# Android notification stays open when launching app

Tags: android, android-intent, alarmmanager, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

I'm able to queue and launch notifications through AlarmManager, I'm also able to launch my application when clicking the notification. Unfortunately the notification isn't removing itself when the application is launched.

Notification setup:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(mainActivity, NotificationPublisher.class);
intent.setAction("handle");

PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mainActivity, 0, intent, 
                                                    PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(mainActivity)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.phone)
    .setContentTitle(title)
    .setContentText(textContent)
    .setAutoCancel(true)
    .setContentIntent(pIntent);
return builder.getNotification();
```

The notification click broadcasts and hits this function:

```
void handle(Context context, Intent intent) {
    System.out.println("handle");
    Context mainContext = Extension.mainContext;
    Activity mainActivity = Extension.mainActivity;
    Intent launchIntent = new Intent(mainContext, mainActivity.getClass());
    launchIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(launchIntent);
}
```

The handle function will launch the activity but not remove the notification from the status bar. Interestingly... If I remove the call to startActivity, the notification will close.

Things I've tried:

- Setting the auto cancel flag manually
- Using the builder.build() instead
- NotificationManger cancel(id) and/or cancelAll
- Using NotificationCompat.Builder
- Using a regular launch intent for the setContentIntent instead of manually calling startActivity

Comment: can you remove it by dismissing "by hand" on device?

Comment: Yes, regular swiping isn't having problems.

Comment: Just to cross check, have you used the same notification id while doing `cancel (int id)` ? I guess there are 4 ways to remove any notifications: 1. user dismissing it 2. setAutocancel 3. `cancel (int id)` and `cancelALL`  And I guess you are not using `Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT` flag..Right? Just one suggestion: try `cancel (int id)` from your `handle` method to explicitly remove it

Comment: I have used notificationManager.notify(0, notification); with notificationManager.cancel(0). It doesn't seem to do anything. I have also tried cancelAll. User dismissing it always works, and auto cancel is set in the builder. I am not using FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT. I have also tried setOngoing(false) to redundantly make sure I don't add it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked around this by launching my App 300ms after clicking the notification.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this statement from your question:

> Interestingly... If I remove the call to startActivity, the
>   notification will close.

I'm assuming that your `Activity` is just reposting the `Notification`.

Comment: I modified the notification to instead launch a separate app that has no notifications. The problem still occurs, therefore this is not my answer.

Comment: OK. Based on all of your comments none of this makes any sense. So there's obviously something funky going on. Hard to debug remotely. Good luck! And please let us know if you figure it out.

Comment: Hey David! Had a big breakthrough last night! I'm using something called OpenFL to build apps. I'm using the sample project from it called (PiratePig). When I did the test related to your comment I created a different app called VanillaPiratePig. PiratePig would make notifications and then VanillaPiratePig would be opened. Last night however I tried opening the gmail app and the bug does not occur. Therefore I'm pretty sure this is a performance bug. Because the OpenFL apps are fairly clunky to start up the android OS class responsible for de-queuing notifications doesn't get a time slice.